# Mysql, left join with select and creating indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fallowing slow sql query (all data is working correct). My problem is that query is working more than ~2sek.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate)), '/', MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate))) AS period,
       COUNT(pixel.id) AS clicks,
       COUNT(postbacktracker.id) AS conversions,
       CONCAT(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(pixel.adddate / 3600, 0) * 3600)), ' - ', (HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(pixel.adddate / 3600, 0) * 3600)) + 1)) AS hour,
       DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(pixel.adddate / 86400, 0) * 86400)) AS DAY,
       CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate)), '/', WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate))) AS week,
       MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate)) AS MONTH,
       YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate)) AS YEAR,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(pixel.adddate)) AS min_date,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(pixel.adddate+1)) AS max_date,
       pixel.adddate AS adddate,
       products.id AS OfferID,
       products.name AS name,
       campaign.id AS id,
       campaign.name AS campaign_name,
       pixel.transaction_id AS TransactionID,
       pixel.url AS url,
       campaign.mkey AS mkey,
       team_users.first_name AS first_name,
       team_users.last_name AS lastname,
       team_users.company AS company,
       team_users.email AS email,
       team_users.hasoffersid AS affiliateid,
       COUNT(userdata.id) AS user_exists,
       SUM(userdata.orders) AS total_operations,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN userdata.orders != 0 THEN 1
             END) AS total_sales,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN 1
             END) AS sales_without_upsells,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN 1
             END) AS sales_with_upsells,
       SUM(userdata.pvalue_sum) AS total_sales_sum,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
           END) AS sales_wo_up,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
           END) AS sales_w_up,
       (SUM(CASE
                WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
            END)/COUNT(CASE
                           WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN 1
                       END)) AS AOVCheckout,
       (SUM(CASE
                WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
            END)/COUNT(CASE
                           WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN 1
                       END)) AS AOVinclupsells,
       (((SUM(CASE
                  WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
              END)/COUNT(CASE
                             WHEN userdata.orders = 1 THEN 1
                         END)) + (SUM(CASE
                                          WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN userdata.pvalue_sum
                                      END)/COUNT(CASE
                                                     WHEN userdata.orders > 1 THEN 1
                                                 END)))/2) AS AOVall,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN userdata.orders = 0 THEN 1
             END) AS presale,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN userdata.orders != 0 THEN 1
             END) AS sale,
       COUNT(pixel_count.id) AS PARTIAL,
       (COUNT(pixel.id) - COUNT(pixel_count.id)) AS sales,
       SUM(userdata.sendtry) AS Declines,
       ((COUNT(postbacktracker.id)/COUNT(pixel.id))*100) AS Cr,
       SUM(postbacktracker.payout) AS Payout,
       SUM(postbacktracker.payout)/COUNT(pixel.id) AS Epc
FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN pixel ON campaign.mkey = pixel.defa
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = pixel.offer_id
LEFT JOIN team_users ON pixel.aff_id = team_users.hasoffersid
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          userkey,
          payout
   FROM postbacktracker
   GROUP BY userkey) postbacktracker ON pixel.transaction_id = postbacktracker.userkey
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT pixel.id,
          COUNT(postbacktracker.id) AS conversions
   FROM pixel
   LEFT JOIN postbacktracker ON pixel.transaction_id = postbacktracker.userkey
   GROUP BY pixel.id
   HAVING conversions = 0) pixel_count ON pixel_count.id = pixel.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT userdata.id,
          userdata.ukey,
          userdata.sendtry,
          COUNT(produktorder.id) AS orders,
          SUM(produktorder.pvalue) AS pvalue_sum
   FROM userdata
   LEFT JOIN produktorder ON produktorder.nekp1stv1r = userdata.nekp1stv1r
   GROUP BY userdata.id) userdata ON pixel.transaction_id = userdata.ukey
WHERE pixel.adddate >= 1527853697
  AND pixel.adddate < 1531223297
GROUP BY campaign.id,
         period
ORDER BY campaign.id,
         pixel.adddate,
         hour ;
```

The problem is in this part of query (without this left join query is done in 0.0035 sek.) :

```
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT pixel.id,
          COUNT(postbacktracker.id) AS conversions
   FROM pixel
   LEFT JOIN postbacktracker ON pixel.transaction_id = postbacktracker.userkey
   GROUP BY pixel.id
   HAVING conversions = 0) pixel_count ON pixel_count.id = pixel.id
```

How should the correctly constructed index for this query look like?

Here is EXPLAIN result:

```
1   PRIMARY pixel       ALL index_defa,index_adddate                231 99.13   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1   PRIMARY campaign        ref index_mkey  index_mkey  902 thanatos.pixel.defa 1   100.00  Using index 
1   PRIMARY products        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   thanatos.pixel.offer_id 1   100.00      
1   PRIMARY team_users      ref index_hasoffersid   index_hasoffersid   4   thanatos.pixel.aff_id   1   100.00  Using index 
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 902 thanatos.pixel.transaction_id   2   100.00      
1   PRIMARY <derived3>      ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   thanatos.pixel.id   10  100.00      
3   DERIVED pixel       ALL PRIMARY             231 100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort 
3   DERIVED postbacktracker     ref index_userkey   index_userkey   902 thanatos.pixel.transaction_id   2   100.00      
2   DERIVED postbacktracker     ALL index_userkey               19  100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: As I wrote I removed selected fields for better readable

Comment: No, all selected data I use as it should be... Result of query are good. My only one problem is with speed of query...

Comment: Oh, and also, this:

`LEFT JOIN pixel ... WHERE pixel.adddate >= 1527832290 AND pixel.adddate < 1531201890`

is functionally identical to this:

`JOIN pixel ... WHERE pixel.adddate >= 1527832290 AND pixel.adddate < 1531201890`

Comment: please.. This is query generated from system and this values comes from datepicker as timestamp... I only need a help with indexes...

Comment: While it may be true, on the evidence provided, I cannot support that assessment.

Comment: ok, I edit my post and put a whole query

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. (Before you spend too much time, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: Cool. That first LEFT JOIN is still a JOIN though, so you might as well write it that way!

Comment: I do not understand. I need only create the indexes...

Answer (score 0):

That is a really strange construct.  I would simply remove it.

Why?

- This is a `left join`, so it is not filtering out any rows.
- The one value in the subquery, `conversions`, is not being used anywhere in the query.

Hence, the `join` does not appear to be doing anything useful and you can just remove it.  (It is possible that it multiplies the number of rows, but I'm guessing that is not useful.)

Comment: No, I just removed selected fields before post. I wanted the whole to be clearer...

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this? This may probably hekp you.

```
SELECT pixel.id,
          COUNT(postbacktracker.id) AS conversions INTO #pixel_count
   FROM pixel
   LEFT JOIN postbacktracker ON pixel.transaction_id = postbacktracker.userkey
   GROUP BY pixel.id
   HAVING conversions = 0


SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate)), '/', MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(pixel.adddate))) AS period,
       CONCAT(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(pixel.adddate / 3600, 0) * 3600)), ' - ', (HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(pixel.adddate / 3600, 0) * 3600)) + 1)) AS hour,
       pixel.adddate AS adddate,
       products.id AS OfferID,
       products.name AS name,
       campaign.id AS id,
       campaign.mkey AS mkey
FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN pixel ON campaign.mkey = pixel.defa
AND pixel.adddate >= 1527832290
AND pixel.adddate < 1531201890
LEFT JOIN #pixel_count AS pixel_count ON pixel_count.id = pixel.id
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = pixel.offer_id
LEFT JOIN team_users ON pixel.aff_id = team_users.hasoffersid
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          userkey,
          payout
   FROM postbacktracker
   GROUP BY userkey) postbacktracker ON pixel.transaction_id = postbacktracker.userkey

GROUP BY campaign.id,
         period
ORDER BY campaign.id,
         pixel.adddate,
         hour ;
```